# How to execute code only when the ArrayList has reached it's last element?

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running a for loop and saving data on firebase inside it.

Here's my code:

```
private int counter = 1;

pProgress.setMessage("Posting...");
pProgress.show();
pProgress.setCancelable(false);

for (int i=0; i<imageArray.size(); i++) {

    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageArray.get(i).toString()));

    String key = database.getReference().push().getKey();

    UploadTask uploadTask = storage.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(key).child("product_image").putFile(file);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            counter++;
            if (counter == imageArray.size()) {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "successfully posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  imageView.setImageResource(0);
                  pDescription.setText("");
                  pDuration.setText("");
                  pPrice.setText("");
                  label.setText("Label");
                  if (pProgress.isShowing()) {
                      pProgress.dismiss();
                  }
            }

            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            imageUrls.add(downloadUrl.toString());
            database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDescription").setValue(pDescription.getText().toString());
            database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDuration").setValue(pDuration.getText().toString());
            database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pPrice").setValue(pPrice.getText().toString());
            if (imageUrls != null) {
                for (int i=0; i<imageUrls.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("imageUrlsSize", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size()));
                    String idtwo = database.getReference().push().getKey();
                    database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child(idtwo).child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                    if (imageUrls.size() > 0) {
                        imageUrls.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to show a `ProgressDialog` and dismiss it when the data is uploaded successfully. Similarly, I want to clear the `EditText` fields and `ImageView` too.

How can I figure out `imageArray` has ended so that I can dismiss ProgressDialog and clear edittext as well as imageview?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of [Murat K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4467208/murat-k)'s answer.

I just shifted this code

```
database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDescription").setValue(pDescription.getText().toString());
database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDuration").setValue(pDuration.getText().toString());
database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pPrice").setValue(pPrice.getText().toString());
```

out of the `for` loop and now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to check the count in your callbacks. You would check it in `onFailure` and `onSuccess`. Something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.size(); i++) {
    final int currentCount = i + 1;
    /** code **/
    onSuccess() {
        if (currentCount == imageArray.size()) // do something
    }
}
```

You may also need to declare `imageArray` as final. This has the disadvantage that you will know that the last element has been processed, but you will have no idea if there are other request still pending. A better approach would be to use a member field in your class e.g.

```
class YourClass{ private int currentCount = 0; }
```

and you would again count this in your callbacks e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.size(); i++) {
        onSuccess() {
            currentCount++;
            if (currentCount == imageArray.size()) // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: both the approaches aren't working. When I'm putting the code in it, it is emptying the edittexts and empty string is getting saved on firebase.

Comment: @HammadNasir What did you do? Could you edit your post with the new code?

Comment: @HammadNasir Change the counter to `0` and also increment it in the `onFailure` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Beeing a Real-time database there is no cetain moment in which we can say that we have loaded all the reconars from the database or that an ArrayList has reached it's last element. This happening because there is a possibility that in every moment something can change, i.e. an item/items can be added or deleted. This is the way in which Firebase was built.

But a short answer to your question, first move the declaration of your `imageUrls` ArrayList inside the `onSuccess()` method otherwise will be null due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. Second, define a variable in your class named `count` and increase the value of it each time `onSuccess()` method is called and compare it with the `size` of your list like this:

```
int count = 0;
onSuccess() {
    count++;
    if(count == imageArray.size() : do somethig ? do something else)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are handling async tasks so you need to encapsulate your job and work with a Queue and callbacks. Try something like that:

```
class Job{
    private Runnable completeCallback;
    private String key;
    private Uri file;

    public Job(String key, Uri file) {
        this.key = key;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void setCompleteCallback(Runnable completeCallback) {
        this.completeCallback = completeCallback;
    }

    void doWork(){
        UploadTask uploadTask = storage.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(key).child("product_image").putFile(file);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                completeCallback.run();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                imageUrls.add(downloadUrl.toString());
                database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDescription").setValue(pDescription.getText().toString());
                database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDuration").setValue(pDuration.getText().toString());
                database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pPrice").setValue(pPrice.getText().toString());
                if (imageUrls != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<imageUrls.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("imageUrlsSize", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size()));
                        String idtwo = database.getReference().push().getKey();
                        database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child(idtwo).child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                        if (imageUrls.size() > 0) {
                            imageUrls.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                completeCallback.run();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Queue {
    ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    private int total;

    public void execute(){
        total = imageArray.size();
        for (int i=0; i<imageArray.size(); i++) {

            Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageArray.get(i).toString()));
            String key = database.getReference().push().getKey();

            Job job = new Job(key, file);
            job.setCompleteCallback(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jobs.remove(job);
                    updateUi();
                }
            });
            jobs.add(job);
        }
        for (int i = jobs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Job job = jobs.get(i);
            job.doWork();
        }
    }

    private void updateUi() {
        Log.d("UI", "Completed " + jobs.size() + "/" + total);    
    }
}
```